# Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::id does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want make auto fill id on add new item. i following tutorial but i get this eror

this is my Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class Kode extends Model
{
    protected $table = "report";
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_permintaan', 'tanggal_permintaan', 'tanggal_pengiriman', 'nama_client', 'nama_client', 'jumlah', 'status'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_permintaan';

    public static function kode()
    {
        $id = DB::table('report')->max('id_permintaan');
        $addNol = '';
        $id = str_replace("PM", "", $id);
        $id = (int) $id + 1;
        $incrementid = $id;

        if (strlen($id) == 1) {
            $addNol = "000";
        } elseif (strlen($id) == 2) {
            $addNol = "00";
        } elseif (strlen($id == 3)) {
            $addNol = "0";
        }

        $idBaru = "PM".$addNol.$incrementid;
        return $idBaru;
    }
}
```

this is my Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Kode;

class ReportController extends Controller
{

    public function tambahreport()
    {
        $id = Kode::id();
        return view('tambahreport');

    }
}
```

this is my View

```
<div class="form-group">
ID Permintaan :<input type="text" class="form-control item" name="id_permintaan" required="required" value="{{ $id }}" id="id_permintaan"> 
{!! $errors->first('id_permintaan', "<p class='invalid-feedback'>:message</p>") !!}
</div>
```

if i click add new item i want my id permintaan auto fill like PM1. and if add item again id permintaan is PM2. how to solve this error. thank you

Comment: "I want make auto fill id on add new item." Then set the table to autoincrement. Don't do it this way. The error message is correct - you don't have an `id()` function in your class. It looks like you meant to call `$id = Kode::kode();`, but again, **you should not handle IDs like this**.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ceejayoz. This looks like poorly written code. There are far better ways to achieve this IMHO.

Anyway to answer your question, The `id()` doesn't exist on the builder instance. So you need to do something like:

```php
$id = Kode::first()->id_permintaan;
```

Or you can use [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding):

```php
public function tambahreport(Kode $kode)
{
    $id = $kode->id_permintaan;
    return view('tambahreport')->withId($id);
}
```